# Steam: The game The Settlers won't launch

Tags: games, steam

Whenever I launch the game "The Settler" via Steam and then press <kbd>play</kbd>, a white thing is shown for a very short while and then nothing happens.

*Does anyone else have the same problem and somehow managed to make it work?*

Comment: You may also want to ask in the Steam and (maybe, if you run Windumb only games) Wine Communities.